# Wait for map response before return (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

here is the code :

```
const [isAcces, setIsAcces] = useState(false); 

useEffect(() => {
    accesList
        .filter((acces) => acces.idAcces === 2)
        .map((acces, index) => setIsAcces(true));
}, []);

return <div>Hello World</div>;
```

I want to render 'Hello World' if 'isAcces' is equal true.
If not, I use `<Navigate to="/" />` to redirect.

I know 'useEffect' is render AFTER the return, but I can't find a solution to solve my issue (and of course, 'isAcces' is always false before the redirection).

I found on Google that I can use the 'Promises', but I don't know how it's work.

Can somebody help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for `isAccess`. That will evaluate before the return, and it depends on `accesList`. And since you're just looking for a boolean based on whether a matching item is in the list, use `some`:

```
const isAcces = useMemo(
    () => accesList.some((acces) => acces.idAcces === 2),
    [accesList]
);

if (!isAccess) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />; // ??
} 

return <div>Hello World</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looping an array and if there are items there that equal 2, you set your isAcces true, correct?

If yes you don't need a map() after the filter

You can simplify your code a bit.

```
function YourComponent({ accesList }) {
  const [isAcces, setIsAcces] = useState(false); 
   
  useEffect(() => {
    const newArr = accesList.filter((acces) => acces.idAcces === 2);
       
    if (newArr.length > 0) {
      setIsAcces(true); 
    }

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAcces) {
      // import history from react-router-dom or any method to navigate to another route
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [isAcces]);

  return <div>hello world!</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const accesList = [{ idAcces: 1 }, { idAcces: 2 }];
  const [isAcces, setIsAcces] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let showHelloWorld = accesList.some((acces) => acces.idAcces === 2);
    if (showHelloWorld) {
      setIsAcces(true);
    } else {
      //history.push("/");
    }
  }, []);

  return isAcces && <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```